# Creating an authenticated Subject with Shiro

Tags: security, shiro

I have a distributed environment (multiple java vms) where the subject is authenticated on one node and should be able to access resources on another node (another VM).

From discussion in 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-323,

I am passing in all the authenticated Subject information to the other VMs via Redis (Principals , Authenticated State etc ..) and am trying to recreate the Subject using new Subject.Builder().buildSubject() way.

My question,
Is there a way to mark this subject as authenticated based on the authentication flag received from the first node ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same technique as I described on your other question:

[Shiro in distributed environment - auto authenticating/white listing internal calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564517/shiro-in-distributed-environment-auto-authenticating-white-listing-internal-ca)

Have special token for "system" users and call login instead of building a subject.